# Consuming WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, soap, wcf-endpoint

When I use Live WCF service it shows error

> There was no endpoint listening at this that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your end-point configuration on `Web.config` on root of your project.

this is sample of a `web.config` with `end-point`.

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="TransportSecurity">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service  behaviorConfiguration="TestWcfHttps1.Service1" name="TestWcfHttps1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="https://MYSERVER/GpTest/Service1.svc" 

                  binding="basicHttpBinding" 

                  bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity"

                  contract="TestWcfHttps1.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="TestWcfHttps1.Service1">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" externalMetadataLocation="https://MYSERVER//GpTest/Service1.wsdl" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The above sample code will fix your problem, but please describe more about your projects on your solution and put your code here. Did you consume the `web-service` in a class library and reference it on your web-app project ?

Comment: Thank you for your Kind response.